# Can an increase be negative?

Tags: word-usage, adverbs, intensifying-adverbs

I'm working on an email to my supervisor with feedback about department meetings. I want to say:

> Our meetings have been increasingly less productive recently.

I could probably re-word it to say "The productivity of our meetings has been declining recently," but I don't want to.    :P

If increasingly means [a situation or quality is becoming greater in intensity or more common](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/increasingly), can it be used to indicate a more and more severe reduction in a quality?